# 400: application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile is not a supported format for <layer> Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

I’m trying to use https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/vectortiles/index.html extension of Geoserver to output my data as pbf. I’m using Geoserver 2.20-SNAPSHOT. I’m following the OL example given on the documentation but the layer is not loading and giving following error

> 400: application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile is not a supported format for
> rfppoc:ne_10m_admin_0_countries what might be going wrong.

Things I have tried already

- check `application/json;type=geojson` , `application/json;type=topojson` , `application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile` under caching default in Vector Layers

Comment: how did you install the extension? and why are you using an old snapshot version? next check the log file for any errors and add them to your question

Comment: Hi @IanTurton, I'm installing as per  https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/vectortiles/index.html . also 2.20 is fairly new right? :/

Comment: nope - 2.20.5 is in maintiance, 2.21.0 is the current stable and if you need a cutting edge snapshot then its 2.22.x-latest